# Getting “use of undeclared identifier”, when I add the getter, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

I am doing the Matchismo assignment from the Stanford website.

So far I have followed the slides exactly the way they are.

Also, this error only shows up when I implement the last method i.e. the getter. If I remove the getter, there's no issue.

The notes can be downloaded from here: [Stanford Course Website](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/373)

Thanks

code:

.m file:

```
    #import "playingCard.h"

    @implementation playingCard

    -(NSString *) contents
    {
        NSArray *rankStrings = @[@"?",@"A",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K"];
    return [rankStrings[self.rank] stringByAppendingString:self.suit];

}

-(void) setSuit:(NSString *) suit
{
    if([@[@"♣︎",@"♥︎",@"♦︎",@"♠︎"] containsObject:suit])
    {
         _suit = suit;
    }
}



- (NSString *)isSuit
{
    return _suit ? _suit : @"?";
}

@end
```

.h file:

```
#import "card.h"

@interface playingCard : card


@property(strong, nonatomic, getter=isSuit) NSString *suit;
@property(nonatomic) NSUInteger rank;


@end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: Solution slide]

Adding one line does the trick!

```
@synthesize suit = _suit;
```

Comment: This is the right fix, and this will happen with the most recent Xcode. If the compiler doesn't write the getter (or setter, though I've never tested that) it doesn't create a backing variable for you.

Answer (score -1):

ALT, moment...you are mistaking something.

You set a `@property` so `suit` is **autosynthesized** to `_suit`.

Then, your getter `isSuit` is logically wrong. I mean that `isSomething` is used to receive a `BOOL` and have a "*more readable*" getter. You don't need in this case to change the name of the getter, and could declare the property just with:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *suit;
```

At this point **you don't need to synthesise anything** because your var is already autosinthesized, and your getter method can be simply:

```
- (NSString *)suit
{
    return _suit ? _suit : @"?";
}
```

It is important that you understand what you are doing.

Enjoy!

Comment: The getter name as `isXxx` is NOT logically wrong, instead it is very common naming convention on iOS. For example, if we want to hide an `UIView`, we will call `self.view.hidden = YES;` while if we want to see if the view is already hidden, we will do something like `BOOL isHidden = self.view.isHidden;`. This can be achieved by adding `getter = isXxx` in the property declaration as stated in this question.

Comment: @Ryan read again my post..of 2 years ago also..I explained that make sense when you have a BOOL...not on a NSString..your example, `isHidden` is a BOOL and is exactly what I said...before writing this comments and downvotes read better and try to understand. Please remove the wrong downvote thanks.

Comment: ok, I admitted it is my mistake to overlook the BOOL/NSString stuff, but you are not answering this question actually.